# Connect ZoneMminder with Galaxy Note 5 Camera

Tags: zoneminder

I hope everyone doing well today

I need someone to help me with Zonemnider(ZM) and it is important to me to write a report for my graduation about ZM.

I am trying out ZM (v1.30.4) to work with mobile camera as security camera or IP camera (Android Galaxy Note5). I am running Ubuntu 17.04.

I have installed “IP-Webcam” on my Galaxy Note5 (Android 7.0, Kernel version 3.10.61s). I have noticed that I can see the video 
through the URL “http://192.168.x.x:xx/” but in ZM dashboard does not show up. I am trying different installation guides from YouTube and here in the blog but none one of them it works. So, please I hope I find a solution for that to finish my report early.

Thank you All

Comment: could you mention how this relates to Ubuntu?

Comment: Because I using Ubuntu 17.04